# Text will not wrap inside my flexbox container

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm having problems trying to get the text inside my flexbox container, instead it just spills out into the element to the right, how can I get both texts to wrap?

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; outline:1px solid red;">
  <div style="width:30%; min-height:450px; outline:1px solid red; position:relative; display:flex;">
    <div style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:25px;">
      <span style="font-size:20px; color:red; margin-bottom:20px; ">kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</span>
      <p style="font-size:15px; color:red; line-height:28px; margin-bottom:20px;">cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:70%; min-height:450px; outline:1px solid red; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:25px; ">
    <table class="section_menu_pala_item_table" data-menu="entrantes" style="width:100%; border:none;">
      <tr class="section_menu_pala_item_row" style="margin-bottom:4px;">
        <th class="section_menu_pala_item_header" style="border:none; text-align:left;" width="15%">Plato</th>
        <th class="section_menu_pala_item_header" style="border:none;" width="1%">1/2</th>
        <th class="section_menu_pala_item_header" style="border:none;" width="1%">1</th>
      </tr>
      <!--append rows here-->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed you haven't accepted any of the given answers to your questions. Aren't you aware of that you are suppose to, if they provide a solution to them? .. And as you also now can an upvote/downvote, it is encouraged to do so on both the very same answers, and any other as well, if there were useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use `word-wrap: break-word`. It will, in contrast to `word-break`, only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing.

As a side note, I strongly recommend start using external CSS style sheets and classes, as with inline you won't be able to reuse styles etc., and it is much more error prone and harder to maintain when mixed with all the markup.

Stack snippet

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; outline:1px solid red;">
    <div style="width:30%; min-height:450px; outline:1px solid red; position:relative; display:flex;">
     <div style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:25px;">
      <span style="word-wrap: break-word;font-size:20px; color:red; margin-bottom:20px; ">kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</span>
   <p style="word-wrap: break-word;font-size:15px; color:red; line-height:28px; margin-bottom:20px;">cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</p>
  
  </div>
 
 </div>
 <div style="width:70%; min-height:450px; outline:1px solid red; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:25px; ">
     <table class="section_menu_pala_item_table" data-menu="entrantes" style="width:100%; border:none;">
            <tr class="section_menu_pala_item_row" style="margin-bottom:4px;">
          <th class="section_menu_pala_item_header" style="border:none; text-align:left;" width="15%">Plato</th> 
                <th class="section_menu_pala_item_header" style="border:none;" width="1%">1/2</th>
                <th class="section_menu_pala_item_header" style="border:none;" width="1%">1</th> 
            </tr>
            <!--append rows here-->
        </table>
 
 
 </div>







</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`break-word` on the div will result in this for ya

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; outline:1px solid red;">
    <div style="width:30%; min-height:450px; outline:1px solid red; position:relative; display:flex;">
     <div style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:25px; word-wrap: break-word;">
      <span style="font-size:20px; color:red; margin-bottom:20px; ">kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</span>
   <p style="font-size:15px; color:red; line-height:28px; margin-bottom:20px;">cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</p>
  
  </div>
 
 </div>
 <div style="width:70%; min-height:450px; outline:1px solid red; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:25px; ">
     <table class="section_menu_pala_item_table" data-menu="entrantes" style="width:100%; border:none;">
            <tr class="section_menu_pala_item_row" style="margin-bottom:4px;">
          <th class="section_menu_pala_item_header" style="border:none; text-align:left;" width="15%">Plato</th> 
              <th class="section_menu_pala_item_header" style="border:none;" width="1%">1/2</th>
                <th class="section_menu_pala_item_header" style="border:none;" width="1%">1</th> 
            </tr>
            <!--append rows here-->
        </table>
 
 
 </div>







</div>
```